How do I embed the Auth0 login box into my own web page?
I am using Auth0's Universal Login, which looks like below:

However, this is a standalone page.
My question is, how to embed this UI component into my own web page?
The desired effect is like:

I checked Auth0's doc but didn't find instructions.
Does it not support it?
If this is the case, are there any other services that I can use?
Or do I have to implement the OAuth procedure myself?
Thanks in advance!
